# read the Form component from @fluentui/react-northstar@0.48.0

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react, fluent-ui

There is a nice looking schema-based **Form** component on [fluentui](https://fluentsite.z22.web.core.windows.net/components/form/definition?showCode=true&showRtl=false&showTransparent=false&showVariables=false#types-form)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Form, Button } from '@fluentui/react-northstar';

const fields = [
  {
    label: 'First name',
    name: 'firstName',
    id: 'first-name-shorthand',
    key: 'first-name',
    required: true,
  },
  {
    label: 'Last name',
    name: 'lastName',
    id: 'last-name-shorthand',
    key: 'last-name',
    required: true,
  },
  {
    label: 'I agree to the Terms and Conditions',
    control: {
      as: 'input',
    },
    type: 'checkbox',
    id: 'conditions-shorthand',
    key: 'conditions',
  },
  {
    control: {
      as: Button,
      content: 'Submit',
    },
    key: 'submit',
  },
];

const FormExample = () => (
  <Form
    onSubmit={() => {
      alert('Form submitted');
    }}
    fields={fields}
  />
);

export default FormExample;
```

But they don't offer any method/example to collect the data from what I can tell. (at least not in the documentation). 
I can collect most values from the `onSubmit` event but it get's hacky because not all html components are necessarily input elements that have the `value` attribute. I also don't think this is the intended way to do it. Anyone can enlighten me please? I think you must be able to feed the onChange function to it somehow. Or am i supposed to add the onChange function in each field-object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up combing through the library components (Forms Input and Checkbox) to see what makes them tick.

This is what I ended up with. Please feel free to improve on it should anyone else stumble on this in the future.

**Note** the use of the attributes `defaultValue` and `defaultChecked` to set the initial value of the Input and Checkbox components respectively. As well as the `onChange` event passing the `name` and `value` parameters for the Input component and `name` and `checked` for the Checkbox component.

The Checkbox label must be inside the Control if you wish it to appear next to the checkbox, otherwise it will appear above the checkbox.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Button, Checkbox, Input } from '@fluentui/react-northstar';

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  state = {
    email: "",
    password: "",
    remember_me: true
  }
  fields = [
    {
      label: 'Email',
      name: 'email',
      id: 'email-inline-shorthand',
      key: 'email',
      required: true,
      inline: true,
      type: 'email',
      control: {
        as: Input,
        defaultValue: this.state.email,
        onChange: (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: value })
      }
    },
    {
      label: 'Password',
      name: 'password',
      id: 'password-inline-shorthand',
      key: 'password',
      required: true,
      inline: true,
      type: 'password',
      control: {
        defaultValue: this.state.password,
        onChange: (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: value }),
        as: Input,
      }
    },
    {
      name: "remember_me",
      key: 'remember_me',
      id: 'remember_me-inline-shorthand',
      type: 'boolean',
      control: {
        label: 'Remember me',
        as: Checkbox,
        defaultChecked: !!this.state.remember_me,
        onChange: (e, { name, checked }) => { this.setState({ ...this.state, [name]: checked }) }
      },
    },
    {
      control: {
        as: Button,
        content: 'Submit',
      },
      key: 'submit',
    },
  ]

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    console.log("submitting these values", this.state)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Form
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        fields={this.fields}
      />
    )
  }
};

export default Login;
```